# Suspend & Hibernate not working on a Toshiba Satellite L300

Tags: 12.04, suspend, hibernate, toshiba-satellite

I am using Toshiba Satellite L300. Installed Ubuntu 12.04 as fresh install. Just after the installation, I tried hibernating the system using command pm-hibernate , which went well. The suspend too worked automatically. Two days ago, I found that the suspend isn't working. The suspend button takes to the resume screen. The same with hibernate. I suspected a kernel update has caused this. But booting into older kernels isn't helping. Hate Toshiba for making laptops incompatible with Ubuntu. But can anyone suggest any fix for this problem for now. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think, this is a bug. The same goes for Casper's Nirvana Series. Even if you are out of battery, system goes to lock screen after suspend-like behaviors again and again.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open your Terminal.
2. Run `sudo modprobe toshiba_acpi`.

Did that fix the problem?  If so, you can:

1. Open your Terminal, if it's not already open from before.
2. Run `sudo nano /etc/modules`.
3. Add `toshiba_acpi` to the end of the file.
4. Save and exit.  This loads the `toshiba_acpi` module on boot.

You can, alternatively, add the following to the end of the file `/etc/rc.local` (creating the file if it does not already exist):

```
modprobe toshiba_acpi
exit 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Like erdemkeren says this is a bug, please report it on Launchpad.
for more a howto: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs

Comment: Thanks for the help. Reported as bug on launchpad on this link https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1023720